# how to create a collection select link

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

Let's say I have an app that lists different clubs in different cities around the world. In the index action of clubs_controller.rb, I return all the clubs unless a city parameter is provided

```
def index
   if params[:city] 
        @clubs = Club.where(:city_id => params[:city])    
   else
        @clubs = Club.all
    end 

end
```

In order to make that work, I want to create a dynamic collection select link where the user can select the city. Right now, I'm doing this, but this is creating a link for each city, which is not what I want.

```
 <% City.all.each do |city| %>
    <%= link_to city.name, clubs_path(:city => city) %>
 <% end %>
```

Is there a way to create a link where I link changes depending on the city selected?

One SO answer linked to this blog that explained  how to do it with jquery http://marcgrabanski.com/articles/jquery-select-list-values but the page has now been taken down.

Comment: I didn't get your requirement. 
You mean, in a form you want that user should be to select a city and depending upon the city selected all clubs in that city are made available in another city select drop-down.

Comment: Or you want the links to all the cities and on clicking a city, user is taken to index page of clubs displaying all clubs of that city?

Comment: Instead of 10 links with 10 city names, I want one link with the option to select different cities in it. If the user selects New York, then the param passed will be for the id to New York  `<%= link_to 'New York', clubs_path(:city => new_york_id) %>

Comment: In that case you need to submit a form. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass params like this in a link.

```
<%=  link_to city.name, {:controller => "clubs", :action => "index", :city => city.id} %>
```

**Update**
You can submit a form to the index page.

```
<%= form_tag clubs_path, :method => 'get' do  %>
  <%=  select_tag :city_id, options_for_select(City.all.collect{ |c| [c.name, c.id] })  %>
<%= submit_tag "Get Clubs", :name => nil %>
```

Also in your controller you can check for param city_id.

Comment: This is not what I want.Thanks for trying.

Comment: Thanks so much. The update you provided was what I was looking for.